# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'parse'

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading data from excel file and while parsing the excel data into data stream I am thrown with this attribute error.

Data frame is built so the data is fetched. What am I missing?
The lines reading and parsing are:

```
xl=pd.read_excel('data_file.xlsx') #Read from excel file
dfs=xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0]) #Parsing the excel into data stream
```

The error i get is:

```
File "C:\Users\Meghna\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__ return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'parse'
```

Comment: that is because you are using pandas `read_excel()` , use [`Excelfile()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've confused [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with [`pd.ExcelFile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelFile.parse.html):

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("data_file.xlsx")

sheets = dict()
for sheet_name in xl.sheet_names:
    sheets[sheet_name] = xl.parse(sheet_name)
```